# Can you help me code woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce in wordpress, I want to show number of customers who are ordering that product (has not yet been processed)

Demo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj3rM.jpg

Comment: If you have a specific question about a particular piece of code, post that. Otherwise, there are tons of WooCommerce tutorials on line.

Comment: Hi Difster, I added, can you help me?!

Comment: Are you looking to show how many people have a particular item in their cart or how many people have ordered and paid but not been processed?

Honestly, you might consider the business case for what you're doing before proceeding.

Comment: This question is not logical. I think you need to rewrite it before someone will consider helping you. Some hints:

Comment: I want to show the number of orders, including paid but has not been yet processed!

I don’t speak English very well :)

Comment: This question is not logical. I think you need to rewrite it before someone will consider helping you. Some hints: 'number of customers who are ordering that product' and 'total sales' are not the same which one do you want? A product does not have an order quantity. But, an order item does but I can't see how it makes any sense to reset that to zero. Did you mean total sales of that product? Even if you can't write perfect English it is important and also doable to get the right nouns. As it is I don't think anyone will respond to this question. I would carefully rewrite this.

Comment: Thank Cuda, I have rewritten :)  hope you help me!

Comment: 'I want to show the number of orders, including paid but has not been processed yet' - this is different from the original question. It is important to have a clear idea of what you want otherwise your question won't make any sense. When I first started coding one of the mistakes I often made was to write code before I had completely and thoroughly thought out the design. Now, before I start writing code I have a complete design in my head or on paper if it is large enough. Anyway, your question is not consistent and I think you need to achieve this before anyone will help you.

Comment: It's simple, I want to show number of customers who are ordering that product (this process is not yet processing or complete)
You can look at the picture!

Thank Cuda!

Comment: Some advice from an old man - I suppose you are doing this for employment. It is really important that your writing be professional. If you write illogical things your reputation will suffer and your employment prospects will diminish. It is important that what you write be logical. If takes several hours to get a professional result I would take several hours. I don't think you are making extra effort to be professional and it shows. Take time, think thoroughly, write carefully so you look like a professional.

Comment: I understand but I can't expressed in English, I don't speak English very well :(

Answer (score 1):

put the below code in your function.PHP file

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_product_sold_count', 11 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_product_sold_count', 11 );

function bbloomer_product_sold_count() {
    global $product;
    $units_sold = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'total_sales', true );
    echo '<p>' . sprintf( __( 'Units Sold: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</p>';
}
```

in above code you can see the units sold in product single page/ Product detail page and looping page.

Comment: Thank Gupta!
I want to show number of customers who are ordering that product (this product is not yet processing or complete)

* Units Sold is reset to zero when processed is processing or complete

Comment: this link will help you on this https://www.skyverge.com/product/woocommerce-display-order-count/